# How to link a static library in gcc with other dynamic libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, static-libraries

The static library is: /home/jonathan/Dropbox/C++/teapotgame/bin/liblua.a

The current gcc command im using is: `gcc -std=c++11 -DLUA_USE_LINUX -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lopenal files.o -o bin/bin`

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 -DLUA_USE_LINUX -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 files.o -o bin/bin -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lopenal /home/jonathan/Dropbox/C++/teapotgame/bin/liblua.a`

Comment: Always put source files *before* libraries.

Comment: Is that *really* your linkage command line? And is it successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no principal difference whether you link against dynamic or static libraries (besides the -l prefix and omitting the file extension for shared libs). The order of the libraries can matter though. If you have circular dependencies, you have to list the same library twice.